# how do I insert elements into a vector from right to left?

Tags: c++, arrays, vector, stl, insert

Let's say I have a vector which consists of elements:

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

and I have another vector which consists of:

`9 8`

After adding both of them the result should be:

`9 8 1 2 3 4 5 6 7`

This is what I have tried to do:

```
v1.insert(v1.begin() + 0, 9); //at the beginning of v1 insert 9
v1.insert(v1.begin() + 0, 8); //at position 1 of v1 insert 8

for (int i = 7;i > 0;i--)
    {
     v1.insert(v1.end(), v2[i]);
    }
```

The result is `987654321`

Answer (score 4):

You are traversing the vector from right to left (i 7 down to 0). One way is to go from 0 to 7. Another way:

```
for (int val : v2) {
  v1.push_back(v2);
}
```

or

```
v1.insert(v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
```

Answer (score 1):

Alternative approach using STL:

```
std::copy(v1.begin(), v1.end(), std::back_inserter(v2));
```